# Make one sticky key not sticky on Windows

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I don't use the right control key at all and I like to utilize it as a conveniently placed hotkey for some custom function which I can do easily with Autohotkey.

The problem is I also use sticky keys for convenience and if I hit right control then the new function bound by Autohotkey is activated, but the control key also goes into sticky state (because it is done at the OS-level), so it unwantedly affects the next key pressed.

Is there a way to tell Windows somehow (with an extra tool maybe) I do want all modifiers to be sticky, except the right control key?

Answer (score 2):

Though I'm not completely sure, I wonder if keys that are mapped through the registry (mapped at the system level) might not be considered modifiers anymore... I'm not totally sure, but if you'd like:
Open Regedit
Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout
Within the Keyboard Layout folder (don't go any lower), see if you have a key called "Scancode Map". If not, create a Binary key called "Scancode Map", and edit the binary to read:

```
00000000 00000000 02000000 00001DE0 00000000
```

Then restart your computer.

For understanding:
The first 16 zeros are meaningless for these purposes.
The "02" is the number of keys you want to map, +1.
The next 6 zeros... Also meaningless.
The next 4 zeros is the scancode you want to map **TO** (0000 = Nothing).
The next 4 Hex digits are the scancode of the key you want to **change** (1DE0 = Right Control).
Last 8 zeros... More filler.

[Scancode Mapping](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/archive/w2kscan-map.mspx)

In case your worried about losing it as a script hotkey, you can map it to any scancode... And I'm sure AHK has the ability to act on scancodes as well as keys. I think they call them Virtual Keys in AHK. Just remember the scancode you set it to, and make sure the scancode isn't in use by something else (unless you wanna map 2 different keys to do the same script, then go hard).